# Understanding Unity player movement 2d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I know how to do Unity 3d movmement and its very simple but when I started to do 2d movement I got very confused on what the code actual means Im new to Unity and C# and I would like to understand what this code means

```
        if (horizontalInput > 0.01f)
        transform.localScale = Vector3.one;
    else if (horizontalInput > -0.01f)
        transform.localScale = new Vector3(-1, 1, 1);
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
        body.velocity = new Vector2(body.velocity.x, speed);
```

Answer (score 0):

This code applies transformation to the entity. There's no much context but I'll try my best as I've worked with Unity.

```
if (horizontalInput > 0.01f)
    transform.localScale = Vector3.one;
else if (horizontalInput > -0.01f)
    transform.localScale = new Vector3(-1, 1, 1);
```

What the whole structure is doing here is applying a scale to the entity base on the value of `horizontalInput`. In the `if`, you scale positive to the local X axis. In the `else if`, you scale negative to the local X axis You can get the documentation of localScale here [Transform.localScale](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-localScale.html)

`Vector` is a class and `one` is a static property that represent the unitary vector (1, 1, 1). It's a shorthand useful so you don't have to write `new Vector3(1, 1, 1)`

```
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
    body.velocity = new Vector2(body.velocity.x, speed);
```

This block here uses `Input` to check for a user event. In this case, if the user pressed the spacebar. `Input` class is used to get information from your keyboard, mouse, etc. `Keycode` is a class that lists several key codes (as you might know, every key is assigned a code that can help to identify the key in case of a user event). See [Input](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.html).

If user is pressing the spacebar, it applies a `Vector2` to `body.velocity` to move your entity. Of course, it is not written but I'm guessing that `body` is a `RigidBody2D` instance because `velocity` is a property of such class used to move it. See [Rigidbody2D.velocity](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D-velocity.html)

You may be wondering why it uses `Vector3` in a 2D context. Both `Vector2` and `Vector3` represent vectors, but `Transform.localScale` requires a `Vector3` to work as this property is applicable to both 2D and 3D context. `Rigidbody2D.velocity` on the other hand is only 2D (X and Y axis) as the class name implies.